# Android. RecyclerView changes text size in list items after change screen orientation

Tags: android, text, size, android-recyclerview

Sorry for my poor English.

I added

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in XML manifest

I restore RecyclerView's position by this code

```
mRecycleViewParceble = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();     
doRefreshAdapter();//Create and set adapter
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mRecycleViewParceble);
```

But after screen rotation and refreshing list text in list comes to be smaller. But I set 14sp in xml. And not change this size in runtime.

This happens on customer's Sony Xperia P (ICS). On my devices everything is fine.

What does they do. Refresh list in portrait orientation, change to landscape, refresh list -> text in list items comes to be smaller. Please help ...